# Leveraging a New Part-Time Job to Transition into Full Time?

Tags: resume, career-development, software-development, developer

I have recently been trying to transition into doing full-time work at a company as a junior developer but have had some issues I am seeking advice about. I have applied for about 100 jobs so far and have had a few interviews.

I was offered one front-end developer position. They wanted me to go full time, but they are only offering an extremely low rate. Like the absolute bottom end of the lowest possible rates ($15.00/hr, no benefits, and I have a stay at home wife and 15 month old). I told them I would do part-time so they could see how much value I provide, and will be happy to transition to full-time if they agree to pay me a higher rate.

I usually am able to charge $32.50/hr as a freelancer so even though the pay cut is massive, I think the experience working on a team will be worth it in terms of leveraging into a better pay rate/new full-time position since I literally have no experience working for a larger business in a team environment).

They agreed and I start today.

**Is it okay for me to continue to seek opportunities elsewhere while I am doing part-time work for them?**

My thought process is, I should seek a better paying position somewhere else, and if I get it, go back to the company I am working part-time for and tell them, “I have been contacted by another company who is willing to pay me x, if you are willing to match that, I am happy to turn them down and go full time here.”

**Also While looking for other opportunities, should I put this position on my resume even though I literally just started?**

Will this look weird/odd to employers to see I just started but am looking for a new job already?

Is this appropriate? How would you handle this situation/what advice if any do you have for someone looking to make this transition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, you are free to do as you please with your time outside of work. The exception to this would be if you signed something stating that you won't 'freelance' or 'moonlight', or if you signed an NDA/Non-compete that prevents you from working in the same industry for a period of time during and after employment.

Similarly, put the position on your resume, it IS a part of your employment history after all. There is no harm in showing where you work, though you should be prepared to answer questions as to why you're looking for work so soon after starting (even if it's for additional part time work).

Finally, and as a tangent to what you had posted in the first paragraph of your question: Compensation is an aggregate of what you receive. Salary (or hourly rate) is only one piece of your compensation. Any form of 401(k)/403(b)/pension, any paid vacation, perks, benefits, access to stock options, healthcare insurance etc. All add to the cost of employing you. While part-time usually don't receive much in the way of benefits, you should still look an consider what the value of those benefits are to you. For example, one year I made ~$56,000 as an industrial programmer, that same year my healthcare premiums added up to nearly $40,000, bringing my compensation total over $100,000 (when you factor in 401(k) and vacation). This correlates with the effective rate I would have gotten as an independent contractor in the same field, even though I made effectively 50% of a typical IC's rate. The difference being the independent needs to source their own insurance, retirement, and vacation pay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider what benefits you get from employment.  Right now, you have to drum up business somehow, and that's unpaid.  When you're employed, drumming up business is somebody else's problem, and you don't have those unpaid hours.

Depending on the company and your relationship to them, you might get paid time off, health insurance, 401(k) matching, training on company time with company money, and other things.  You'll probably get better benefits full-time than part-time.  I don't know what you're getting, or what you'd get working full time, so you have to figure what the benefits (if any) are worth to you.

The general rule of thumb is that you charge considerably more for freelance or  contract work than you would get paid as a full-time employee.  The usual rule of thumb is twice as much, but I never did find a contract position that would pay me twice as much per hour as a corresponding full-time job.

So $15/hour isn't completely out of line compared to your freelance rate, if the benefits are good.  It would be a pay cut in any case, but the experience and the addition to the resume are also worth something.  It may be way below market rate for your area.

If you find a job that pays a lot better, and decide to take it, take it.  Do not try to use it as negotiating leverage, and never accept a counter-offer from your current employer.  Market rate is something you can bring up when discussing salary, and that's as far as you should go.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it okay for me to continue to seek opportunities elsewhere while I am doing part-time work for them?

Totally fine to do this. You shouldn't settle, and you can probably do much better, especially if you are part-time.

> Also While looking for other opportunities, should I put this position on my resume even though I literally just started?

Totally fine as well. I would say that you are simply evaluating all of your options and seeing if there are better opportunities. However, don't say that you `had` to accept the job or anything to weaken your position with companies you may interview with.

Showing that you got a job may signal to a potential employer that at the very least another company thought you were worth a shot.

`What else can you do?`

Besides gaining experience while on the job, take this time to work on some side projects to beef up your resume, practice interviewing, and do everything else you can to make you a more competitive applicant. You'd be surprised at the difference a month or two of this can make, even if it is a half an hour a night.